# Is there a step function or method for cv.glmnet?

Tags: r, glm, glmnet

One can perform `glm` model fit with logistic link function for response from `binomial` family and then can apply `step` function to extract the best subset of explanatory features in terms of information criterion such as AIC or BIC.

Have anyone performed such procedure for an output model from `cv.glmnet`function or `glmnet` from `glmnet` package? Can you suggest how one can reproduce the same methodology used on regular `glm` model and `cv.glmnet` model?

This below doesn't look like it would work:

```
modelAIC <-step( object= model$glmnet.fit, direction = "backward")
```